# ShellExecute() link error in Windows Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors, shellexecute

I am getting this linker error in my Visual Studio 2010 project:

ASWHighScores.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ShellExecute referenced in function _ASWLaunchURL

```
int ASWLaunchURL(const char* url)
{
   ShellExecute(NULL, "open", url, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
   return 0;    // noErr
}
```

Why would I be getting a linker error? Did a google search, nothing came up.

I have verified that shell32.lib is indeed being linked against in Visual Studio 2010's Linker -> Additional Dependencies settings. (It's automatically an "Inherited value" but I also added it to the custom list to be sure.)

Comment: Do *not* declare this function yourself, it's name is not actually ShellExecute.  Be sure to `#include <shellapi.h>` so you get the proper version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling it `ShellExecuteA`. Usually this substitution is made automatically by a macro defined in the Microsoft header files, but maybe there's something about your setup which is missing this.

Comment: ASWHighScores.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ShellExecuteA referenced in function _ASWLaunchURL

Comment: @VernJensen, you must be missing either the include file header specifying the function or the library. Nothing else can explain it.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks! Was missing #include <Shellapi.h>. I wouldn't have guessed that a missing header could cause *link* errors, but apparently they can.